# Simulating modality with QGraphicsWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to show a custom context menu on a QGraphicsView. Because [QGraphicsWidget doesn't support modality](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicswidget.html#details), I'm currently using a QWidget with Qt::ApplicationModal.  However, I'd really like to use a QGraphicsWidget, because 1) I find it more flexible than QWidget, and 2) all my other widgets are derived from QGraphicsWidget. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?  Is there, e.g., a straightforward way to disable events to all the other objects in the scene?

Comment: You could use a (semi-)transparent overlay widget that expands over all scene and catches mouse events, much like it's done on web pages. Also you can make all graphics items share the same parent, excluding modal items, so you can disable the parent item and its children altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @PavelStrakhov. The overlay widget is one idea I had thought about but didn't know how easy it would be to keep it  in sync with the scene below it if that scene resized or scrolled or whatever. I hadn't thought about sharing a parent, though. That sounds like a pretty interesting idea. I'll kick those ideas around a little bit.